# terraform do not get variable passed through modules

Tags: terraform, hashicorp

I want to provision a simple terraform vpc and subnet.

I created a module and declared all the variable required in the module variable.tf

and passed wrote all the needed values through terraform.tfvars

but when I run terraform apply I get a prompt to insert a value for avail_zone

main.tf

```
module "myapp-subnet" {
    source = "./modules/subnet"
    subnet_cidr_block = var.subnet_cidr_block
    avail_zone = "us-east-1a"
    env_prefix = "dev"
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.myapp-vpc.id
    default_route_table_id = aws_vpc.myapp-vpc.default_route_table_id
}
```

modules/subnet/main.tf

```
resource "aws_subnet" "myapp-subnet-1" {
    vpc_id = var.vpc_id
    cidr_block = var.subnet_cidr_block
    availability_zone = var.avail_zone
     tags = {
        Name: "${var.env_prefix}-subnet-1"
    }
}


resource "aws_internet_gateway" "myapp-igw"{
    vpc_id = var.vpc_id
    tags = {
        Name: "${var.env_prefix}-igw"
    }
}

# using existing route table
resource "aws_default_route_table" "default-rtb" {
    default_route_table_id = var.default_route_table_id
     route{
        cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/10"
        gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.myapp-igw.id
    }
    tags = {
        Name: "${var.env_prefix}-main-rtb"
    }
}
```

module/subnet/variables.tf

```
variable vpc_cidr_blocks {}
variable subnet_cidr_block {}
variable avail_zone {}
variable env_prefix{}
variable vpc_id {}
variable default_route_table_id {}
```

terraform.tfvars

```
vpc_cidr_blocks = "xxxx"
subnet_cidr_block = "xxxx"
avail_zone = "xxxxxx"
env_prefix = "dev"
myip = "xxxxxxx"
instance_type="t2.micro"
public_key_location= "/home/xxxxxxxx/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
```

Comment: Do you have `variables.tf` defined in the root module as well?

Comment: yes. I have defined variables.tf in the root module

Comment: Does that file have `avail_zone` variable defined?